# Error with bracket placement

Tags: java

I am getting this error : `Syntax error on token "}", { expected after this token`

I am not sure what the problem is here and I've checked that the brackets match, or so I think, so I am not entirely clear of how to fix this problem

```
 import java.awt.*;


public class Player extends Entity {

    private int directionX, directionY;
    private Main instance;

    private Rectangle hitbox;

    private int life = 3;

    public Player(Main instance, int x, int y){
        super(x , y);
        this.instance = instance;
        width = 16; height = 16;

        hitbox = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        move();

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(hitbox.x, hitbox.y, hitbox.width, hitbox.height);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Lives: " + life, 20, 20);
    }

    private void move(){
        if(!instance.getStage().isCollided(hitbox)){
            directionY = 1;
        } else { directionY = 0;
        hitbox.x += directionX;
        hitbox.y += directionY;
        }
    } // <<<<<< Getting error here <<<<<<<<<<

    if(instance.getEnemyManager().isCollided(hitbox)){
        if(life > 0){
            life--;
            hitbox.x = 800 / 2 - width / 2;
            y = 390;
        } else {
            instance.setGameOver(true);
        }
        }


    public void setdirectionX(int value){
        directionX = value;
    }

    public void setdirectionY(int value){
        directionY = value;
    }
}
```

If anyone could answer this question I'd be very happy to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code in the problematic area:

```
private void move(){
    if(!instance.getStage().isCollided(hitbox)){
        directionY = 1;
    } else { directionY = 0;
    hitbox.x += directionX;
    hitbox.y += directionY;
    }
}

if(instance.getEnemyManager().isCollided(hitbox)){
```

The closing brace is the end of the method... and then you've got an `if` statement which is in the middle of the class declaration, not in any method. Did you intend that to be part of `move()`? If so, you need to remove the closing brace just before it.

Note that in your post at least, the indentation is all over the place. It *really* helps if you get your IDE to format your code, so you can see what code is part of what method, etc. It makes it a lot easier for other people to read, too...

Answer (score 1):

You write

```
if(instance.getEnemyManager().isCollided(hitbox)){
    if(life > 0){
        life--;
        hitbox.x = 800 / 2 - width / 2;
        y = 390;
    } else {
        instance.setGameOver(true);
    }
    }
```

outside any method, that's why your compiler is warning you